# Scale latex table in rmarkdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I have a number of latex tables that I want to compile into a pdf document. I have been using rmarkdown using the \input command. I would like to scale the latex table in Rmarkdown using the same \input command and have been unsuccessful. I don't want to read these latex files into R and would simply like to scale these tables in Rmarkdown.

Originally I did the following to generate a pdf document using RMarkdown.

```
\input{sample_table1.tex}
\input{sample_table2.tex}
\input{sample_table3.tex}
```

I have tried and keep getting ! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

```
\resizebox{0.75\textwidth}{!}{    \input{sample_table2.tex}}
```

My latex files are in the following format:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Scaling elements which contain text, like a table, [is a bad idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text). You will get much better results if you choose a suitable font size instead.

Comment: Is it possible to rescale text within rmarkdown? I prefer to not generate the tables each time tables don't fit.

Answer (score 0):

Scaling elements which contain text, like a table, is a bad idea. You will get much better results if you choose a suitable font size instead.

If your tex distribution is reasonable new, you can use hooks to smuggle the font size change from the main file into your included file:

```
\documentclass{article}

% just for this example because I don't have your included files
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{sample-table.tex}
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
test & test & test & test & test\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}


\AddToHookNext{env/tabular/begin}{\tiny}
\input{sample-table.tex}


\end{document}
```